# Deploying a docker container from Github to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker-compose, raspberry-pi, github-actions, continuous-deployment, cicd

I currently have multiple docker containers running on a Raspberry Pi in my home network as a way to easily run all my projects simultaneously. I now want to improve that setup by hosting my code in github repos and deploy new changes in the repo to my Pi.

E.g. for my current project I'm building a FastAPI backend which gets build in a Dockerfile and then launching a Celery-, Redis- etc. and my own Backend-Image via a Docker-Compose File.

This setup should then be deployed from Github to my local Pi who is not reachable from outside of my home network. I thought if there's a way like a self-hosted Github-Runner on the Raspberry who can then deploy the changes to my Docker setup.

Does anybody know how that can be accomplished?

I set up the Dockerfile for my self-made backend and generated a Docker-Compose file to manage the needed images. I currently use that setup for developing locally on my Pc and now I want to deploy that Docker setup to my Raspberry Pi via Github pushes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.